# .Net Framework 3.5 and .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 have same version number?

Tags: .net, version

I have heard I can check my .Net Framework Version from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5.

There are two entries SP and Version. .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 has value 1(true) for SP entry.

In this part, I have a question. .Net Framework 3.5 has same version number with .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and there is only one difference of SP entry value?

For example, I know that version entry value is 3.5.30729.12345. However I don't know about SP entry value. In that case, can I convince version entry value indicates .Net Framework 3.5 SP1?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to determine which versions and service pack levels of the Microsoft .NET Framework are installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/318785/how-to-determine-which-versions-and-service-pack-levels-of-the-microso)

> Use the registry information below to determine which version(s) and
>   service pack level(s) of the Microsoft .NET Framework are installed.
>
> **v3.5    Original Release**
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5
> Name: Install, Type: REG_DWORD, Data: 1
> Name: SP     , Type: REG_DWORD, Data: 0
> ```
>
> **v3.5    Service Pack 1**
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5
> Name: Install, Type: REG_DWORD, Data: 1
> Name: SP     , Type: REG_DWORD, Data: 1
> ```

Below in the same article, under **Recommended Deployment Detection** header:

> To detect the existence of a specific .NET Framework version
>   regardless of the Service Pack level, or to detect a service pack
>   level or a later service pack level of the same .NET Framework
>   version, use the registry information that is listed in the following
>   table.
>
> **v3.5    Any Version**
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5
> Install = 1
> ```
>
> **v3.5    Service Pack 1 or Greater**
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5
> SP >= 1
> ```

Comment: Is there a way that detects v3.5 is either SP1 or not without SP information? I think version rule may help me.

Comment: `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" -v SP` The `SP` value seems to be _Service Pack_ number (or _Original Release_ if equal to zero).

Comment: Read [List of .NET framework versions](https://jonathanparker.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/list-of-net-framework-versions/)